# Animating map fill color through time

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial, r-sf, gganimate

I am trying to animate a map of Texas over time, such that the fill color changes depending on if an `event` happened.

However, I keep getting the following error message: `Error: arguments have different crs`.

I suspect the error is related to the fill in `data_map` but I'm not entirely sure. Any ideas on what this error message means and/or how to animate this time series of Texas?

I have been using section 3.3 of this website ([link here](https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/220339/time-maps-tutorial-v2.html?sequence=3&isAllowed=y#the-base-map)) as a guide.

Example Data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(geodata)
library(sf)
library(gganimate)
library(gifski)

# Polygon of the state of Texas in USA

tx <- gadm(country = 'USA', level = 1, path=tempdir()) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  filter(NAME_1 %in% 'Texas') %>%
  mutate(State = NAME_1) %>%
  select(State, geometry) %>%
  st_transform(crs = 4269)

# Data to use for map

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 3))
colnames(df1)[1:4] <- c('State','date_start','date_end','event')
df1$State <- 'Texas'
df1$date_start <- c(as.Date('2020-01-02'),
                    as.Date('2020-01-10'),
                    as.Date('2020-01-16'))
df1$date_end <- c(as.Date('2020-01-05'),
                  as.Date('2020-01-13'),
                  as.Date('2020-01-24'))
df1$event <- c('moderate','strong','severe')

df1 <- left_join(df1,tx, by = 'State')

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 31))
colnames(df2)[1] <- 'date'
df2$date <- seq.Date(as.Date('2020-01-01'),
                     as.Date('2020-01-31'),
                     1)

dat <- left_join(df2, df1, by = join_by(between(date, date_start, date_end))) %>%
  select(date,event,geometry) %>%
  mutate(geometry = tx$geometry)

# Create basemap of Texas

base_map <- ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(geometry = geometry),
          color = "black", fill = "white") +
  theme_void()
base_map

# Add data to basemap

data_map <- base_map + 
  geom_sf(data = dat,
          mapping = aes(geometry = geometry,
                        fill = event)) +
  transition_time(date)

# Animate map

animate(data_map, nframes = 31) # throws error message
```

Comment: Apparently, this is a relatively recent bug in ```gganimate``` [link here](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/479)

Comment: EDIT: According to the link above, you need to downgrade the ```gganimate``` AND ```transformr``` packages using ```install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/gganimate/gganimate_1.0.7.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")``` and ```install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/transformr/transformr_0.1.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")``` respectively. This allowed the code above to run properly.

Comment: Thank you!!! This tip helped me a lot!!!